# Understanding the memory layout of a 4-byte integer

Tags: memory, assembly, integer, mips, endianness

I am working with the MIPS architecture (not sure if this is relevant since we are dealing with memory).

I am told that A 32-bit integer is in memory at physical address 0x00A0CE48.
I assume that number is 00000000111111110000000011111111.

The system is byte-addressable, what value would be at memory address 0x00A0?

I wasn't sure if the first 8 bits were at address 0x00, next 8 bits at 0x00A0, next 8 bits at 0x00A0CE, and the last 8 bits at 0x00A0CE48? I'm asking because I have to manipulate a value in 0x00A0, but im not sure what's there.

Part of the problem is to 1st assume big endian is used, then little endian.

A 32-bit integer resides in memory at physical address 0x00A0CE48.  The bits within the 32-bit word are numbered 0 to 31 from least significant bit to most significant bit. The code below extracts a single bit from this 32 bit pattern and places the bit into $t4.

```
lui    $t0,0x00A0
ori    $t0,$t0,0xCE48
lbu    $t4,2($t0)
srl    $t4,$t4,5
andi   $t4,$t4,1
```

The next question in my assignment is to indicate the number of the bit (0 through 31) within the 32-bit word that is left in $t4 if the memory order used is little-endian or big-endian.

Comment: Do you understand hexadecimal numbers?  Are you aware that `0x00A0CE48` is nowhere near `0x00A0`?

Comment: "I'm looking for house #12345678. I'm standing near house #1234. Who lives in house #123456? Are they related to the people in house #1234 or house #12345678?"

Comment: So if Im told that a 32 bit integer is at  0x00A0CE48, does that relate at all to what is in memory location 0x00A0? I just posted the whole problem to give you a better idea of why I am asking. I can explain the mips instructions, but the first step is to get the 1st 16 bits from address 0x00A0, thats why I asked.

Comment: My guess is that those first two instructions are constructing the value `0x00A0CE48` in `$t0`.  This is then used as an address in the `lbu` instruction, with an offset of 2 (so it actually loads a byte from `0x00A0CE4A`).  Nothing is being loaded or manipulated at `0x00A0`.

Comment: @JohnnyRocket - no, nowhere near. The four bytes of your 32-bit integer are stored at consecutive byte-addresses: 0x00A0CE48, 0x00A0CE49, 0x00A0CE4A, 0x00A0CE4B.  These addesses, in your example, may contain [0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF] or [0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00], depending on endianness.  address 0x00A0 is nowhere near this location, as explained by the other posters, so no, no relation at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On a big endian system, the most significant byte is stored first. So, assuming the value is 0x12345678, 0x12 will be stored at address 0x00A0CE48, 0x34 will be stored at address 0x00A0CE49, 0x56 will be stored at address 0x00A0CE4A, and 0x78 will be stored at address 0x00A0CE4B.

On the other hand, on a little endian system, the least significant byte will be stored first. So, 0x78 would be stored at 0x00A0CE48, and so on.

Note that if a 32-bit word is stored at address 0x00A0CE48, the next word will be four bytes later, at address 0x00A0CE4C. The arithmetic should be performed on the address as a whole. You cannot consider the bytes making up the address separately when reading from memory.

In the assembly you've posted, `lui` (which stands for "load upper immediate") will shift the immediate value 16 bits to the left and store it in $t0. After that instruction, the value in $t0 will be 0x00A00000. The next instruction will OR the contents of $t0 with 0xCE48 and store the results in $t0. After that, $t0 will contain your full address, 0x00A0CE48.

Comment: Thanks! I am looking at the 1st instruction  lui    $t0,0x00A0       It loads the 1st 16 bytes from the integer starting at 0x00A0 into $t0. Based on what I have, would I know what is located at memory address 0x00A0. I'm a noob, sorry.

Comment: You would not know what is at 0x00A0, and you wouldn't need to. The first two instructions simply construct the address, in two steps. The first of them, `lui`, loads the most significant 16 bits of the address. (You're not reading from the address 0x00A0. You're simply copying the value 0x00A0 into the upper 16 bits of the register.) The second instruction, `ori`, fills in the least significant 16 bits. The read, which is performed by `lbu`, adds 2 to what's in register $t0, and then reads from that memory address. 0x00A0CE48 + 2 gives you 0x00A0CE4A.

Comment: ahh, I see. So lets assume the 32 bit integer we start with are numbered from 31-0(msb to lsb). So if we use little endian, after the lbu instruction, $t4 would contain (24 zeros) + bits 23-16. Then, the srl instruction shifts the value in t4 right by 5 places, which leaves 21 zeros + 3 bits, 15-13, in t4. Then and immediate ands bits 15-13 with 1, so I'm confused as to how the problem is asking me to determine which of the bits(0-31) are left in t4 after the instructions are executed.

Comment: `lbu` will read a single byte. Assuming that byte is 0xFF (this will depend on endianess), after the `lbu`, $t4 will contain 0x000000FF. `srl` will then shift this quantity 5 places to the right. `andi` will compute `0x1 & (the result of the srl)`.

Comment: Excuse the last comment: lets assume the 32 bit integer we start with are numbered from 31-0(msb to lsb). So if we use little endian, after the lbu instruction, $t4 would contain (24 zeros) + bits 23-16. Then, the srl instruction shifts the value in t4 right by 5 places, which leaves 21 zeros + 3 bits, 23-21, in t4. Then and immediate ands bits 23-21 with 1, so I'm confused as to how the problem is asking me to determine which bit(0-31) are left in t4 after the instructions are executed

Comment: Your analysis is correct, except that after the `srl`, you'll have 29 0's and the 3 bits, 23-21. The `andi` will AND that with a number consisting of 31 0's and a single 1 in the least significant position. Which of the three bits of the original number are you left with?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5674/discussion-between-ray-and-johnny-rocket)

Comment: So just to make sure I'm clear, if we have 0x20000 in t2, then execute lb $t0,13($t2), $t0 would have the byte located in 0x2000D?

Comment: Yes, except `lb` would have two operands, not three.